# How to synchronize navigation property and foreign key?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6.1

With enttity framework 6.1 code first, I try to synchronise a navigation property with the foreign key.

See my class for the License entity with a foreygn key on Product :

```
public partial class License
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public System.Guid Guid { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public System.DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ProductId")]
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

in the winform code, I create a License entity and in the selected value changed event of a combobox I set the product navigation property :

```
public partial class NewLicenseForm : Form
{
    public NewLicenseForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Entities = ServicesProvider.GetService<Entities>();
        this.License = this.Entities.Licenses.Create();
    }

    public Entities Entities
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public License License
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    private void productsComboBox_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox productsComboBox = sender as ComboBox;
        if(productsComboBox == null)
            return;

        if(productsComboBox.SelectedValue != null)
        {
            this.License.Product = this.Entities.GetProductById((int)productsComboBox.SelectedValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Why this.License.ProductId is not synchronised when the navigation property is set? what is wrong?

Comment: Whre is your DBContext? Whern are you saving the entity? Have you enabled change tracking proxies?

Comment: My DBContext is this.Entities, I don't want save the entity, i have enabled change tracking proxies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the new entity in the dbset

```
this.License = this.Entities.Licenses.Create();
this.Entities.Licenses.Add(this.License);
```